# after login having error 'Anonymous User' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I m new in Django  m creating a signup form if  submit the form the data is stored success fully but I m having a error in redirection or login
**view.py**

```
from Blog.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def signup_form(request): 
    form=SignupForm() 
    if request.method=='POST': 
       form=SignupForm(request.POST) 
       if form.is_valid():
         user=form.save() 
         user.refresh_from_db()  
        # load the profile instance created by the signal
         user.save()
         raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
         user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
         login(request, user) 
         return HttpResponseRedirect('home/')
return render(request,'blog/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

redirecting in setting file
**setting.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT='home/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/logout'
```

my form file look like that
**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email','password']
        labels={'username':' Enter User Name','password':' Enter Password','email':'Enter Email','first_name':'Enter First Name','last_name':'Enter Last Name'}
        widgets={'password':forms.PasswordInput,'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your User Name'}),
        'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your Password'}),
        'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your Email'}),
        'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter First Name'}),
        'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Last Name'})
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
path('signup/',views.signup_form,name='signup/'),
```

'Anonymous User' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: you can use a `login_required` decorator which is in `django.contrib.auth.decorators`.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the user when you save the form, so you don't need to call `authenticate` since you already provide the `login()` function so I have removed `authenticate` and `login` line:

```
def signup_form(request): 
    form=SignupForm() 
    if request.method=='POST': 
       form=SignupForm(request.POST) 
       if form.is_valid():
         user=form.save() 
         user.refresh_from_db()  
        # load the profile instance created by the signal
         user.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('home/')
     else:
         return render(request,'blog/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: sir if i will use login required before signup then it will ask login before signup it not work sir

Comment: @manuGupta I have edited my code